# 'GetUsresList' object has no attribute 'META'

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve mongodb data and displaying that data in html using `render_to_response`.Here is my code

```
class GetUsresList(View):

def get(request,self):
    dta = db.user_details.find({},{'userName':1,'mobileNumber':1,'emailId':1,'_id':0})
    print dta
    return render_to_response('users_details.html',{'dta':dta},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But i am getting the following error.

```
'GetUsresList' object has no attribute 'META'
```

I think the error is with `RequestContext`.

What is the mistake i am doing.Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the 'self' param first in the method.

Why you print dta?

Try this more simple:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

class GetUsresList(View):

    template_name = 'users_details.html'

    def get(self, request):
        dta = db.user_details.find({},{'userName':1,'mobileNumber':1,'emailId':1,'_id':0})
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'dta': dta })
```

Have you look at the built-in [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)?